# How to correctly manage dependencies with Functional Programming

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, functional-programming

Function A has 3 dependencies on other functions. Function B has 3 dependencies on other functions. Function C combines both functions and will provide the dependencies to function A and B.

But what if function C is used in another function which combines functions like C? This is when the providing part of the dependencies start to explode.

I can't seem to find a simple answer on the "way to go" is in this case.

The "reader monad" looks promising. Though some say dependency injection (framework) is not OK while in OOP it solves the issue very well.

I hope you can help me to find a single best practice for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged *dependency-injection* I'm assuming that by *dependencies*, you mean the kinds of dependencies used in Dependency Injection (DI): database access, web service calls, time providers, GUI views - in general, [Strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

There's a subset of Strategies where all Strategies are deterministic and have no side effects - in other words, [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). When you pass one pure function to another pure function, you are, by definition, defining a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). That's fine.

In general, however, [DI makes everything impure](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection). Passing an impure action to a function makes the composed function impure as well. If you want to adopt Functional Programming, you must model things differently.

[The Reader monad doesn't solve that problem](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/21/contravariant-dependency-injection).

A good place to start is with the [Functional Core, Imperative Shell](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell) architecture, AKA the [Impureim Sandwich](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/03/02/impureim-sandwich). [Push impure actions to the boundary of the system](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/18/functional-architecture-is-ports-and-adapters), and compose pure functions from other pure functions.